# "Add an App" on publishing site is eternally "loading"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have successfully added a provider hosted app to the app catalog.

However, when I go to the main site, then go to the "gear" icon, and select "Add an app", it gets stuck at "Loading" forever.

If I view javascript errors, in `IE 10` see:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'className' of undefined or null reference 
ScriptResource.axd, line 5 character 59249
```

And in Firefox I see:

```
Error: TypeError: b is null
Source File: https://blah.test.net/ScriptResource.axd?d=SsARyFD3_rQCMDLd6IgfYaxJnLFnvxkC1Xtj47fGS-nQa4JCl2bx2MyfQ9rvUL53P-WbzGFUoUC-lVUcbrX5lHQ6RNC1BnccNHsuuoi76QciKDMPANw6dKkz8pgiX5fuW6ysOtL6n0GoF-4xlZkviLwqYgxj75pJxS4GjF0C38uNL2diSVl0z48saetHiQmE0&t=6119e399
```

Line: 5

I retried the request and then grabbed the most recent logs via SharePoint management console with the below command:

```
get-splogevent -starttime (get-date).addminutes(-1) | fl message > error.txt
```

Examining the error logs, I can't find any smoking gun.

How can I fix this so that I can add an appmodel app to a publishing site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug in the SharePoint master designer in SharePoint 2013 RTM.

See: http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html

Basically, you have to ensure that your master page contains specific items.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Just removing Visible=False from DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar fixed my issue. MS should have a fix for this as its been existing since 2012

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Specifically, if you are using Sharepoint Designer 2013, your code should look like this (notice Visible="false" has been removed)

Answer (score 2):

**This problem may occur due to the following reasons:**

- You might have a system custom master page in which certain placeholders were deleted or had their visibility set to false.
- The app installation service timer job is disabled.

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, you should revert the current master page to the default, non-customized version in order to load your Apps correctly. Alternatively, if you choose to retain your custom master page, ensure that any missing placeholders are added, as mentioned at **[Add an App Stuck on Loading in SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/your-apps-stuck-loading-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Comment: Unable to access the above URL @Qassas

Comment: @Suriya Thank you so much, for your feedback,  it's a strange behavior! I have resolved the link! and it can be accessible now :)

Answer (score 1):

add the below lines in the master page, it works for me, also place it under this section

```
<div class="ms-hide">:

 <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
 <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">-->
 <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```