# I can't get custom master page to add new apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, custom-masterpage

I'm using a custom master paged based off of oslo. When i made the master page I copied the oslo.html file and added breadcrumb navigation. When I go to "Add an app" I get stuck at this loading screen:

[image]

I was looking at this [site](http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html) and it said I need to add certain line to my master page. When I looked through my master page I saw that these lines where already in the code the exact way specified. I'm not sure what I need to do to get the "Add an app" working again.

Note: When I switch site to the OOTB Oslo I can load the apps.

Comment: Check your console for any hints, issue could be some javascript not being loaded, see if scripts such as init.js, MicrosoftAjax.js are loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I found a fix the the error I was getting here:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81103/add-an-app-on-publishing-site-is-eternally-loading

Answer (score 3):

Quoting this [article](http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html):

The key to fixing this problem is to make sure your master page includes:

*DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar*, *PlaceHolderLeftNavBar*, *DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea*, and *PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea* and that each of them is not set to *Visible=False*. To do this in an HTML master page with Design Manager you would add the following snippets:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Comment: Perfect. This worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does your problem still exist? This may help:

[Bug in Oslo.htlm](http://changecase.net/blog/2014/04/07/fix-sharepoint-2013s-broken-add-an-app-feature-in-oslo/)

You have to switch from `visible: false` into `true` AND to add `visible: true` at the last two rows. If not, you can't also see the user and groups on the left site from website settings.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue might occur because of**

- You may have used a system custom master page that some placeholders were deleted or its visibility set to false.
- The app installation service timer job is disabled.

To troubleshoot the issue, you should revert the current master page to the default, non-customized version in order to load your Apps correctly. Alternatively, if you choose to retain your custom master page, ensure that any missing placeholders are added, as mentioned in **[Add an App Stuck on Loading in SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/your-apps-stuck-loading-in-sharepoint-2013/)**